# CSS3 Infinite Loop Transition

Tags: javascript, css, transform, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am trying to animate a clock but I am having a lot of trouble trying to get the numbers to loop infinitely. I am moving the numbers by incrementing `translateY()` but when the 59th second is reached all of the other numbers fly past as it transitions back to 0. I would like a smooth transition over to 0 to continue to 1 and so on without showing anything in between.

I've tried `transition: none`, `animation-play-state: paused`, transitionEnd event listeners and even delays but I wasn't able to use any to achieve what I'm looking for.

**Link to code on JSFiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/bwr4yz0s/](http://jsfiddle.net/bwr4yz0s/__)**

The code below outlines one failed attempt:

```
/*Seconds*/
if (sec === 0){    
  /*Move to fake 0*/
  $("#secn").css({transform: 'translateY(-100px))'});

  /*Turn off animation*/
  //$("#secn").css({transition: 'none'});

  /*Move back to actual 0*/
  //$("#secn").css({transform: 'translateY(0px)'});

  /*Turn animations back on*/    
  //$("#secn").css({transition: 'all 0.8s'});

}
else{    
  vert = sec*20 + 'px'; 
  $("#secn").css({transform: 'translateY(-'+vert+') translateZ(0)'});
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try combining your translation with transition:none, for example: `$("#secn").css({transition: 'none', transform: 'translateY(-100px) translateZ(0)'});`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/haxxxton/bwr4yz0s/3/ just remember to add the transition back in afterwards

Comment: you'll also need to apply this same transition killing and fake 0 stuff to the minutes, and hours reels too :)

Comment: perhaps also look at combining functionality into re-useable functions http://jsfiddle.net/haxxxton/bwr4yz0s/5/